# Can I do a auto-expanding group in Word, and create it in VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2016

In my (technical) document I have a few blocks (warning/ tip/ note etc), similar to admonitions. A sample is below.

At the moment, they are created manually : a grouped block of a shape, a text field, and an image. The text does not autoexpand the shape, so after text edit, the shape size must be changed.

My goal is to have similar style auto-expand with the text (so that rounded frame follows the text), and as step 2 create everything in VBA code, to make certain things parametric.
Unfortunately the macro recorder in Word won't let me modify properties around groups and text frames while recording, so it's difficult to see actions needed.

A sample of the warning is below. The red lines show alignment of the triangle, the red arrow shows expansion of text.

[image: Sample of a warning box]

The group should have text flowing top/bottom, this is already possible.

Is what I wish for possible with Word at all ? I use desktop version of Office365, Win10, enUS.

Comment: Why not define the group as a [Quick Part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-quick-parts-and-autotext-in-word-7a527697-058f-4967-b8f1-aae0774e4813)?

Answer (score 0):

### Consider using a Frame or Table rather than a Shape and saving as a Building Block/AutoText.

***Frames and Tables can Autoexpand!***

[image: screenshot]

Here is my page on [TextBoxes and Frames in Word](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#StartPage).

Here is my page on [Tables](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/tables.htm).

Here is my page on [AutoText, Building Blocks, and AutoCorrect](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm).

Frames can be saved as part of a paragraph style and will autoexpand to hold content. However, they are rectangular is shape. You can place your triangle inside a frame along with a Content Control for your text and save it as a building block for future use.

To put an image in a frame, first insert the image and select it, then apply the style for the frame to the selection.

You could also save it as an AutoCorrect entry.

Likewise, tables autoexpand, are rectangular in shape, and can be saved as a building block or AutoCorrect.

Here is a [temporary link to a document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufcs3ceo1xvvfh2/deleteme%20frames%20tables.docx?dl=0) containing these two constructs.

You can't get the rounded corners, but otherwise I think either of these will meet your needs.

**Creating this in vba would be a challenge.** Save as a building block, and if you want, you can use vba to insert it. I'm not sure why you would want to unless part of a larger vba project. You can [assign keyboard shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) to building blocks. Here is my writing on how to [use vba to insert a building block](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock).

[Insert a Building Block Using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66235138/word-vba-insert-a-table-of-contents-building-block/66245344#66245344) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you for input, I will try the suggestions. Reason for VBA is to parametize some factors, I have a small VBA form to insert various.  
I tried yesterday replacing the inner text frame with a table (so, table in shape), that worked fine. Shapes can have option "fit to text". Unfortunately this option is disabled if dragged manually at any point.

Comment: Then use one of the ways to manually create your alert box and save it as a building block / autotext / quick part. Use vba to insert the building block. The building block and your vba should be stored in the same template if possible. (This makes it easier to manage/distribute.)